# Spring-websockets : Spring security authorization not working inside websockets

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, websocket, spring-websocket

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which we have Spring-security for authentication and authorization. We are working on migrating to Spring websockets, but we are having an issue with getting the authenticated user inside a websocket connection. The security context simply doesn't exist in the websocket connection, but works fine with regular HTTP. What are we doing wrong?

WebsocketConfig :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/app").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

In the controller below, we are trying to get the currently authenticated user and it's always null

```
@Controller
public class OnlineStatusController extends MasterController{

    @MessageMapping("/onlinestatus")
    public void onlineStatus(String status) {
        Person user = this.personService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();
        if(user!=null){
            this.chatService.setOnlineStatus(status, user.getId());
        }
    }
}
```

security-applicationContext.xml :

```
  <security:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
    <security:http pattern="/org/**" security="none"/>
    <security:http pattern="/jquery/**" security="none"/>
    <security:http create-session="ifRequired" use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" username-parameter="j_username" password-parameter="j_password"
                             login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" default-target-url="/canvaslisting"
                             always-use-default-target="false" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=auth"/>
        <security:remember-me key="_spring_security_remember_me" user-service-ref="userDetailsService"
                              token-validity-seconds="1209600" data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
        <security:logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"/>
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/cometd/**" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/app/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')" />
<!--        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https"/>-->
        <security:port-mappings>
            <security:port-mapping http="80" https="443"/>
        </security:port-mappings>
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/" success-handler-ref="myLogoutHandler"/>
        <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession">
            <security:concurrency-control session-registry-ref="sessionReg" max-sessions="5" expired-url="/login"/>
        </security:session-management>
    </security:http>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember stumbling across the very same problem in a project I was working on. As I could not figure out the solution using the Spring documentation - and other answers on Stack Overflow were not working for me - I ended up creating a workaround.

The trick is essentially to force the application to authenticate the user on a WebSocket connection request. To do that, you need a class which intercepts such events and then once you have control of that, you can call your authentication logic.

Create a class which implements Spring's `ChannelInterceptorAdapter`. Inside this class, you can inject any beans you need to perform the actual authentication. My example uses basic auth:

```
@Component
public class WebSocketAuthInterceptorAdapter extends ChannelInterceptorAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DaoAuthenticationProvider userAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    public Message<?> preSend(final Message<?> message, final MessageChannel channel) throws AuthenticationException {

        final StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);
        StompCommand cmd = accessor.getCommand();

        if (StompCommand.CONNECT == cmd || StompCommand.SEND == cmd) {
            Authentication authenticatedUser = null;
            String authorization = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader("Authorization:");
            String credentialsToDecode = authorization.split("\\s")[1];
            String credentialsDecoded = StringUtils.newStringUtf8(Base64.decodeBase64(credentialsToDecode));
            String[] credentialsDecodedSplit = credentialsDecoded.split(":");
            final String username = credentialsDecodedSplit[0];
            final String password = credentialsDecodedSplit[1];
            authenticatedUser = userAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
            if (authenticatedUser == null) {
                throw new AccessDeniedException();
            } 
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticatedUser);
            accessor.setUser(authenticatedUser);    
        }
        return message;
    }
}
```

Then, in your `WebSocketConfig` class, you need to register your interceptor. Add the above class as a bean and register it. After these changes, your class would look like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private WebSocketAuthInterceptorAdapter authInterceptorAdapter;
    

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/app").withSockJS();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.setInterceptors(authInterceptorAdapter);
        super.configureClientInboundChannel(registration);
    }
}
```

Obviously, the details of the authentication logic are up to you. You can call a JWT service or whatever you are using.

Comment: Can you tell me from which class is WebSocketChannelInterceptorAdapter ? Thank you.

Comment: The class should be `WebSocketAuthInterceptorAdapter`. I edited my answer.

Comment: I implemented similar code and I can get User inside Interceptor, but in service when I use `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` I get error: `An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext`

Comment: Sorry for responding this late. It's been a while since I've done anything related to Spring Websockets. I assume this error must mean that something is not configured properly in Spring Security and the authorization you're setting is not interpreted by the framework.

Comment: Per my observation, unlike a normal http request - where everything is handled within a thread, so you can use SecurityContextHolder(basically some TheadLocal stuff). In websocket, the thread where you setAuthentication(typically in ChannelInterceptor) and the place  you getAuth(typically in service or controller layer) are totally of different thread. So SecurityContextHolder is not applicable here, I think we can use Principal or SimpMessageHeaderAccessor to get user and pass it to service layer, or setAuth in your controller and use it in your service(since they reside in same thread)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SockJS + Stomp and configured your security correctly, you should be able to connect via regular username/pw authenticator like @AlgorithmFromHell and do

```html
accessor.setUser(authentication.getPrincipal()) // stomp header accessor
```

You can also connect via http://{END_POINT}/access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}. Spring security should be able to pick it and do loadAuthentication(access_token) via ResourceServerTokenServices. When this is done, you can get your principal by adding this to your impl of AbstractSessionWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer or WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer. When doing this, for some reason, the loaded Pricipal is saved in "simpUser" header instead.

```html
@Override
  public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
    registration.interceptors(new ChannelInterceptor() {
      @Override
      public Message<?> preSend(final Message<?> message, final MessageChannel channel) {
        StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);
        if (accessor != null && StompCommand.CONNECT.equals(accessor.getCommand())) {
          if (message.getHeaders().get("simpUser") != null && message.getHeaders().get("simpUser") instanceof OAuth2Authentication) { // or Authentication depending on your impl of security
            OAuth2Authentication authentication = (OAuth2Authentication) message.getHeaders().get("simpUser");
            accessor.setUser(authentication != null ? (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal() : null);
          }

        }
        return message;
      }
    });
  }
```